# Javascript Unit converter lb to kg

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a weight converter that takes pounds(lb) and converts it to kg and vice-versa in the total, I can't seem to get the logic of it right, here is my code, I don't want to use any libraries or frameworks because I want to learn the fundamentals of JavaScript, and also don't know how to implement the discount option.

Here is what I was able to do.

```js
var appleWeight = +document.getElementById('weight1').value;
var orangeWeight = +document.getElementById('weight2').value;
var grapeWeight = +document.getElementById('weight3').value;
var bananaWeight = +document.getElementById('weight4').value;
var totalWeight = appleWeight + orangeWeight + grapeWeight + bananaWeight;
document.getElementById('total_weight').innerHTML = totalWeight;
console.log(totalWeight)
var applePrice = +document.getElementById('price1').value;
var orangePrice = +document.getElementById('price2').value;
var grapePrice = +document.getElementById('price3').value;
var bananaPrice = +document.getElementById('price4').value;
var totalPrice = applePrice + orangePrice + grapePrice + bananaPrice;
var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;
var discountAmount = (totalPrice * Number(discount)) / 100

var finalPrice = totalPrice - discountAmount

document.getElementById('total_price').innerHTML = finalPrice;
console.log("total price " + totalPrice)

var lb = document.getElementsByTagName('select'.value)
```

```html
<h1>JS Grocery Shop</h1>

<span class="label">Apple</span> <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight1" value="3.5" />
<select><option>kg</option><option class="lb" value="lb">lb</option></select> @ $<input type="number" name="price" id="price1" value="2.3" /><br />

<span class="label">Orange</span><input type="number" name="weight" id="weight2" value="5" />
<select><option>kg</option><option class="lb" value="lb">lb</option></select> @ $<input type="number" name="price" id="price2" value="3.0" /><br />

<span class="label">Grape</span> <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight3" value="2.0" />
<select><option>kg</option><option class="lb" value="lb">lb</option></select> @ $<input type="number" name="price" id="price3" value="1.5" /><br />

<span class="label">Banana</span><input type="number" name="weight" id="weight4" value="1" />
<select><option>kg</option><option class="lb" value="lb">lb</option></select> @ $<input type="number" name="price" id="price4" value="0.5" /><br /> Discount : <select id="discount">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="5">5%</option>
              <option value="10">10%</option>
              <option value="15">15%</option>
              <option value="20">20%</option>
            </select>
<br><br> Total Price : <span id="total_price"></span><br /> Total Weight : <span id="total_weight"></span>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: you're not accounting for changing the amounts (of fruit in the basket) or converting from kilos to lbs never mind the discount! Start with the conversion from kgs to lbs..

Comment: the problem is i cant convert lbs to kgs in the final weight amount